# Amazon S3 do not return 100 continue, how?

Tags: http, amazon-s3, http-status-code-100

I want to upload a file to S3. I create a httpconnnection(s3.amazonaws.com), and i send the head={'Date': 'Fri, 18 Jul 2014 03:24:08  +0000', 'Host': 'xx-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com', 'Content-Length': 32, 'Authorization': 'AWS AKIAI2V3MxxxOOKYAAA:JrjeT5rTxCl752tMWEZ0knEE3Zw=', 'Expect': '100-continue'}.

Then i waitting for s3 return a status 100 continue. Saddly, s3 does not return.
This situation did not happen before a week.

And if i use httpSconnection(s3.amazonaws.com), s3 will return status 100 continue.
what happend?

Comment: You're saying Amazon on non-httpS accepts the connection but then never gives a response?

Comment: yes, I can't receive. And I have found the reason that my classmate used Squid Cache software in network's gateway. When you shut down the Squid Cache, it works fine.